# Cant remove right-hand margin

Tags: html, css

I need the width of the whole page to be 1200px, but I must be doing something wrong because when I say for the html to be 1200px (either calling out the html or the body) chrome web dev tools always says its about 1300 px with a large right hand margin? I was looking through similar posts, and added more code that helped other people but it's still there for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
html,body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1200px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    src: url('../fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('opentype');
    font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
    src: url('../fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('opentype');
}

body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

/*GRID*/

.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.half-width{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}

.third-width{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

/*HEADER*/
header{
    border-bottom: 6px #77a466;
}

ul{
    color:#77a466;
    list-style-type: none;
 }

nav{
    float:right;
    padding-top: 25px;
 }

nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'Montserrat-Bold', sans serif;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
 }

 h1{
    line-height: 60px;
 }

h1, h2, h3{
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
span{
    color: #77a466;
}

/*MAIN*/
 img{
    background-size: cover;
    height: 290px;
    width: 1200px;

 }
```

Comment: could you try to reduce your code and build a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also maybe could you build a working example with stackoverflow snippets or something like jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `* {
     box-sizing: border-box
}` to your css.  I also agree with Lux, if you create a live example then it will be much easier to help you come up with a solution.